# Mismo nombre de Columna en datagridview diferentes

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes,

tengo 2 datagridview, pero al agregar una columna en el segundo datagrid que ya esta en el primer datagrid me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible que no pueda tener 2 columnas con el mismo nombre en datagrid diferentes??, tomando en consideración que primer datagrid no tiene ninguna relación con el segundo datagrid.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible, el error se debe a que cada que creas una columna el diseñador crea en tu formulario una instancia de la clase DataGridViewColumn con el nombre de la columna.

Puedes nombrarlas Poli_Codigo1 y Poli_Codigo2 y la propiedad HeaderText nombrar ambas como Poli_Codigo y funcionará como necesitas.

Para evitar que se confundan con tus variables puedes nombrarlos según el estándar usando el nombre de la clase Poli_Codigo1DataGridViewColumn o simplemente Poli_Codigo1Column.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por la explicación me quedo claro